# Search and Checkout display only store view specific products

Tags: checkout, search, catalogsearch

I am working on One Website - Multiple Store functionality. My products are displayed according to store views. I am opening both store urls on two different tabs. But when i search products displayed from stores and when i checkout then also in checkout both products are displayed which are add in cart.I want search and checkout works store specific products only.

Comment: you have to use website level setting for cart share option its only effect on website level not store. go to `system -> configuration -> Customer Configuration and first tab account sharing option`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening in different tabs try to open both in different browser and see if you still have same issue.